Multiple animations for one character
My character is made of multiple objects. I have tried using the action editor, but that doesnt allow for multiple objects to be animated. I just need an idle, walk and jump animation. Is there a way to do this without multiple blend files?


Hello, for this kind of task it would be better to use an armature, if you want each limb to be a separate object, parent each of them to each bone of the armature

Yes, as @moonboots is saying NLA and the action editor are best used when you animate an armature.

Before using NLA -- which I use to implement/integrate multiple basic animations -- I would 1) create a new scene with a linked target object, 2) create multiple Scenes (full copy) of that linked object scene (saves filespace), 3) animate each scene's object into a new action (e.g. walk cycle), use AE to rename the action with something more descriptive, 4) then use another Full Copy Scene (of a linked object scene) with the NLA editor to combine/sequence your named actions.

I've added a rigid armature now, thank you!

Firstly I recommend moonboots suggestion of using armatures for characters.  Nonetheless this answer will apply to armatures or mesh objects animatable.
You're question is more about integrating separate actions such as walk or jump cycles.
Before using NLA -- which I use to integrate multiple basic animations -- I would....

create a base scene with the object mesh defined:



create a full copy, delete the objects that will be animated, and then go back to the obj-definition scene and link them:



From this scene create a full copy for each type of animation (e.g., walk cycle), and in these scenes, animtate the objects and edit the name in the AE to something more referential:



Finally in the scene you want to combine (NLA), selected each object in turn and in AE drop-down locate the action in the drop-down, Push Down (to NLA), and drag/drop and slide for your timing of each and possibly create transitions:


my rudimentary example: 
If this look daunting, well, so are many techniques in the arcane world of 3d modeling n animation!
